# How to sum dice rolls and find the best option in R

Tags: r, dice

I am writing a player function for a game. In this game is you roll 4 dice and use the sums of different dice pairings to get numbers between 5 and 10. I have coded summing each of the different dice together and their outcomes, as well as making sure they are in the correct boundaries (5 to 10). I do not know how to rule out a die once it has been used. This is what I have done so far:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izbj1.png)

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Please post your code as text (use copy/paste!), don't post a picture of your code.

Comment: Can you give an example of what output you want if e.g. Roll_dice is `c(1,3,5,6)` or `c(5,5,5,6)` along with an explanation of how you get there?

Comment: `sumSRD` are the sums of all possible combinations of 1, 2, 3 or 4 dice. Then you keep the sums between 5 and 10. What do you mean by *the best option* and by *to rule out a die once it has been used*?

Comment: @Miff I would want an output of anything between 1 and 4 numbers. for example if the Roll_dice is c(1,3,5,6) you could have the outcomes 10 and 5 by adding 6,3 and one and then 5 respectively. I am writing a code to aim for the higher numbers ie 10, 9 and 8

Comment: @RuiBarradas In the game you have 4 dice and you can sum them in whatever way you want to in order to get numbers between 5 and 10. for example if you got the output from Roll_dice as (2,3,5,5) you could make 3 5's or a 10 and a 5 or even a 7 and an 8 etc. but you can only use each dice value once, so once you have used the 2 in a sum you cannot use it again. By best option I am aiming for the highest numbers or the most

Answer (score 1):

This function rolls a number `d` of dice and computes the sums of combinations of their values according to the rule of having sums between 5 and 10.

```
roll <- function(d = 4){
  f <- function(x) x > 4 & x < 11
  r <- sample(6, d, TRUE)
  r2 <- combn(r, 2, sum)
  r3 <- combn(r, 3, sum)
  r4 <- sum(r)
  c(r[f(r)], r2[f(r2)], r3[f(r3)], r4[f(r4)])
}

set.seed(2021)
roll()
#[1]  6  6  8 10  8 10  6
```